# jQuery accordion - style="display:none; - stops javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an accordion style html code

```
<div class="accordion-link">Link</div>
<div class="accordion-panel" style="display:none;">content</div>
```

with this jQuery script

```
$(function(){
    $('.blog .accordion-link').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('accordion-on'))
        $('.blog .accordion-link').removeClass('accordion-on');
        $(this).toggleClass('accordion-on');
        $(this).next(".accordion-panel").slideToggle().siblings(".accordion-panel:visible").slideToggle();
    })
});
```

In the first accordion tab I'm using a fotorama slideshow.

The problem I'm facing is, that the 'style="display:none;' breaks/stops the execution of the slideshow. How can use the slideshow after toggling the accordion?

Regards
Peter

Comment: a lack of `{ }` after your `if...` statement is a classic cause of problems with JS code. Did you intend for the lines after it to be conditional, and if so, which ones? Even if the behavior is "correct", it may be accidentally so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the inline style "display:none" and added this line of code in jQuery script

```
$('.accordion-panel').css('display','none');
```

This helps fotorama initialize and start - but with the wrong image size.

Adding this line of code to the click(function)

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

resolves the problem. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the inline style from there, and add a parent `<div>` which wraps all that, and then control the slideToggle from there, not on the accordion itself.

```
<div class="acc">
  <div class="accordion-link">Link</div>
  <div class="accordion-panel" style="display:none;">content</div>
</div>
```

Also I'm not sure what your `if` is for but you can just use `toggleClass()`

Answer (score 0):

Hail mary guess

Try:

```
<div class="accordion-panel"style="visibility:hidden;">content</div>
```

I think the plugin is trying to manipulate that css.

Do you have a demo I could look at?  I might be able to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $('.accordion-link').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('accordion-on'))
        $('.accordion-link').removeClass('accordion-on');
        $(this).toggleClass('accordion-on');
        $(this).next(".accordion-panel").slideToggle().siblings(".accordion-panel:visible").slideToggle();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-link">Link</div>
<div class="accordion-panel" style="display:none;">content</div>
<div class="accordion-link">Link2</div>
<div class="accordion-panel" style="display:none;">content2</div>
<div class="accordion-link">Link3</div>
<div class="accordion-panel" style="display:none;">content3</div>
```

I didn't see any wrong with your code